# Retrieving place name from Marker Google Map API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm using Google Place Autocomplete feature to search a place. If there are multiple results, I would like to populate some html fields with the name of place and other information from marker on click. 
Is there any way to retrieve information from marker(standard) and populate text fields with those values?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding AutoComplete service, there's a comprehensive guide and sample in the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) .

The method available for [AutoComplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#Autocomplete) is getPlace() which returns a single place only. But if you intend to display multiple result then I suggest that you use SearchBox instead.

As for populating input texts with location details of corresponding marker, you can achieve it by adding listener for each marker and retrieve the data from Geocoding results:

```
s_markers.forEach(function(s_mark){
s_mark.addListener('click', function() {
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode(
  { 'address': s_mark.title },
 function(results, status) {
  if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){ 

      var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      document.getElementById("address_name").value = s_mark.title;
      document.getElementById("address_type").value = results[0].types;
      document.getElementById("coordinates").value = lat+","+lng;
      document.getElementById("location_type").value = results[0].geometry.location_type;
        }
      });
  });  
});
```

Here's a working JSBin for reference: http://output.jsbin.com/dazitup/

I've also added code snippet below:

```js
var search_markers = [];
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
  var currentarea = {
    lat: -33.8688,
    lng: 151.2195
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: currentarea
  });

  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var s_markers = [];

  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    s_markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    s_markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      s_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.formatted_address,
        position: place.geometry.location
      })
      s_markers.push(s_marker);

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    s_markers.forEach(function(s_mark) {
      s_mark.addListener('click', function() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': s_mark.title
          },
          function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

              var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

              document.getElementById("address_name").value = s_mark.title;
              document.getElementById("address_type").value = results[0].types;
              document.getElementById("coordinates").value = lat + "," + lng;
              document.getElementById("location_type").value = results[0].geometry.location_type;
            }
          });
      });
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 600px;
  width:70%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Marker Labels</title>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDLHKWYAEE2PDjvt6BaBH1SIs4Q93PMpQs&libraries=places"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" style="margin-top:13px">
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
<input id="address_name" type="text" placeholder="Address"><br>
<input id="address_type" type="text" placeholder="Address type"><br>
<input id="coordinates" type="text" placeholder="Coordinates"><br>
<input id="location_type" type="text" placeholder="Location type"><br>

</html>
```